# Nanpy Servo Control

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, servo

*Nanpy allows for a Raspi to have an Arduino slave through python

Right now I'm having extreme difficulty in using the nanpy Servo package, and I cant get it to run correctly. I'm using it to make a robot that is wirelessly controlled from a computer, this is what I have for code:

```
from nanpy import (ArduinoApi, SerialManager)
import pygame
from nanpy import Servo
import time
pygame.init()


a=0
d=0

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Console")

try :
    connection = SerialManager()
    ard = ArduinoApi(connection = connection)
    run = True
except:
    print("Connection Failed!")

servoA = Servo(2)
servoD = Servo(4)
while run :
      for event in pygame.event.get():
                     keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
           # if (event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN):

                     if keys[pygame.K_s] and keys[pygame.K_a]:
                            a=a-1
                            servoA.write(a)
                     elif keys[pygame.K_s] and keys[pygame.K_d]:
                            d=d-1
                            servoD.write(d)

                     elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
                            a=a+1
                            d=d+1
                            servoD.write(d)
                            servoA.write(a)

                     elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
                            a=a-1
                            d=d-1
                            servoD.write(d)
                            servoA.write(a)

                     elif keys[pygame.K_d]:

                            d=d+1
                            servoD.write(d)

                     elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
                            a=a+1
                            servoA.write(a)

                     elif keys[pygame.K_t]:
                            run=False

pygame.quit()
```

This is the error the python shell throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/nanpy/RobotCode.py", line 28, in <module>
    servoA = Servo(2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nanpy-0.9.6-py3.4.egg/nanpy/servo.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.id = self.call('new', pin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nanpy-0.9.6-py3.4.egg/nanpy/arduinoboard.py", line 150, in call
    return _call(self.namespace, self.id, args, self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nanpy-0.9.6-py3.4.egg/nanpy/arduinoboard.py", line 47, in _call
    ret = return_value(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nanpy-0.9.6-py3.4.egg/nanpy/arduinoboard.py", line 18, in return_value
    return serial_manager.readline().replace('\r\n', '')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nanpy-0.9.6-py3.4.egg/nanpy/serialmanager.py", line 101, in readline
    raise SerialManagerError('Serial timeout!')
nanpy.serialmanager.SerialManagerError: Serial timeout!
```

How can I fix this, and/or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the Nanpy firmware loaded onto your Arduino?

Comment: Yes I used this video for my install ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QumIhvYtRKQ

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the port of the Arduino. So could you try:

`connection = SerialManager(device='/dev/ttyACM0')`

or whatever port you are using.

Answer (score 0):

update the configuration file to use the servo and upload it to arduino using the IDE then run this program.

you can find the cfg.h file in nanpy-firmware/nanpy folder.